# Does anybody know what this mini vise-like tool is?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

Found this mini vise-like tool in the deep recesses of my toolbox. I’m sure my son picked it up from somewhere (he’s always buying strange tools) but he can’t remember what it’s used it for.  It is about 2.5” x 3” and has “79168 K8” imprinted on it, but I couldn’t find anything via google.[image]

Comment: Looks like a bicycle chain pin remover/inserter.

Comment: the chain rivet (where it swivels) is placed under the tools pin (below the threaded handle). The chain is secured in tool by the stub-outs on either side of the pin so when pin is extended to push rivet out the chain link is supported and doesn't bend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [Wrench Force Mini Chain Tool](https://www.northrimadventure.com/product/wrench-force-mini-chain-tool-913.htm). You rivet and break bike chains with it.

Comment: I'm going to guess the PIN is missing from it, as the pushing shaft looks WAY bigger than any bicycle chain pin... There is likely a threaded hole in the end of the shaft?

Comment: @markf good point.  It might be a chainbreaker for a motorcycle, but given the amount of thread visible, there is not enough thread to push a pin out of a chain.

Comment: Visible thread isn't a good indicator. The tool can obviously be reversed to retract the pin through the entire jaw width.