# What is the right tool to act as a miniature vise?

Tags: tools

After using my (fancy brand name) sunglasses maybe 20 times, one arm is annoyingly loose—in the vertical direction. I'd still like to get more use out of them before replacing.

All the optician was able to do was to tighten the tiny screw, which I of course had already tried, but as you see below, that doesn't help.

The right solution is to close down the hinge, while the screw itself is out of the way.

[image: hinge in eyeglasses]

What is the right tool to close down a tiny gap such as this? Ordinary pliers would too easily crush this miniature part, as would a vise. A micrometer might act as a surrogate, and perhaps sacrificial, miniature vise. What is the right tool to act as a miniature vise?

A [bike chain tool](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/211425/115116)
might do the trick, but the advance of the pin seems too much per turn for the task. Can you suggest another method/tool?

Comment: Clamping with the blue layer in place will never work. You need to bend the plate to its elastic limit, and then beyond that point by the unwanted gap amount. The elastic deformation will vanish when you remove the clamping pressure. Bending the correct plate is complicated by the typical equal force exerted on the straight plate (assuming you even know for sure which plate is bent). The bent one may have work hardened, making it probable that pliers or a vise will bend the wrong one. Twisting the bridge to make the arms parallel (but the lenses slightly twisted out of alignment) could fix it.

Comment: Maybe take it to a watch repair or jewelry repair specialist?

Comment: If they've only been used maybe 20 times, can you get them replaced by wherever you bought them from? If you used a credit card to buy them, they may be covered by accidental damage insurance for a short time, if they were bent by accident.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about DIY *Home Improvement*.

Comment: How to use tools, and even more importantly, [*which tool to use*](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/291002/23295) is on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pitch of a bike chain tool is plenty fine enough. It might be something like 1mm per turn, so 10 microns (1/100 of a millimetre) is really easy. Adjustment screws of a similar size are often turned by less than a degree in the labs where I work, so a few degrees really is no problem

Answer (score 1):

Any sort of small pliers or needle-nose pliers, wielded with a gentle touch, should do the trick.

Many pliers have serrated jaws to get a better grip on whatever you're holding on to, but in this case, that probably wouldn't be useful and possibly harmful (scratching the glasses). If you can't find any without serrations, just cover them with a couple of layers of masking tape or a layer of duck tape.

Of course, your fancy brand name sunglasses might come with a warranty, or at a minimum, the desire of the manufacturer to protect their name, so you might want to contact them for replacement/repair.

Comment: Part of the trick is that the middle part will need to be "out of the way" as well, since the outer part will "spring back" slightly, so a tight fit can't be gotten by clamping it with the center part in pace - it has to be be bent just a litte more, so it springs back to the right size. Another part of the trick is that the hinge may not be ductile enough to bend back without breaking, depending on the metallurgy of what it's made from.

Comment: Fair points, @Ecnerwal. My take is that the bottom part of the hinge is threaded, but that tightening the screw isn't enough to pull the top part flush. Holding it flush with the pliers before starting the screw would, however, get it to tighten down flush. Of course, this is my take and comes with no guarantees, warranties or other expressed or implied. YMMV. If the burning persists, contact your doctor.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, and if there's any work hardening of the already-bent piece, then under pliers, vise, etc. the straight part is more likely to bend to match the already-bent piece. The obvious fix then is to twist the bridge until the arms are parallel again, but that's suboptimal.

Comment: One wouldn't think, @popham, that there'd be work hardening after only 20 wears of the glasses, but who know.

Comment: I suggest putting something solid in the gap, taking maybe 2/3–3/4 of the space, as it may suddenly give when applying force.

Comment: @FreeMan, work hardening is a metallurgical thing that comes with the plastic deformation of many metals. Assuming the bent piece was once straight, there's a good chance that its elastic limit is now higher than that of the unbent piece, where equal but opposite force on the two plates bends the currently unbent one. Geometric differences between the two plates could mitigate, but assuming same geometry top and bottom seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Hemostats are a great tool to keep in your home toolbox. As essentially a set of small needle-nose pliers, they have a surprising number of uses. I bet two sets would be perfect for this - one to hold the middle section and one to hold the section to be bent. The ones pictured below are straight, they also come with a hooked end. Jewelry supply stores sell ones without serration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a watchmaker's hammer. A wood cutting board would make a nice foundation to support the bracket from below while you whale on the bent piece with that hammer.

Comment: Percussion is the answer, not pinching, +1.